# Vectorizing an easy loop in R

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I am trying to improve my code, but there is a task where I am not able to vectorize a loop. I have 5 sparse matrices, where I have to loop through and add a 1x3-vector resulting from the non-null elements to another matrix. In this example I work with only 1 sparse matrix to keep it simple.

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m[1, 2] <- 5
m[3, 3] <- 8
n <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=5)


for (i in 1:nrow(m)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(m)){
    if (!m[i,j]==0){
      n[i, j:(j+2)] <- n[i, j:(j+2)] + rep(m[i, j], 3)
    }
  }
}
```

The code works, but I have the feeling that there are much better solutions with vectorized functions. I tried and failed with apply functions as the new matrix n has other dimensions as m.

Would be great to get some ideas here.

Comment: what would happen if two values were close to each other in the same row?

Comment: They should be summed up then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized base R solution:

1. Create the `sequence` of indices where you want your values to be inserted. Check `?sequence` to understand how this works under the hood.
2. Insert the values

```r
idx <- sequence(nvec = rep(3, length(m[m != 0])), from = which(m != 0), by = nrow(m))
n[idx] <- rep(m[m != 0], each = 3)
n

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    5    5    5    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    8    8    8
```

Comment: This solution is FAST!

Comment: Amazing use of sequence, that would never have come to my mind. Thanks!

Comment: I need to add this vector to the elements in n. The solution only replaces it. This would not be a problem, but if for example m[1,2] and m[1,3] are not 0, both elements would have to be added to n[1,3] and n[1,4]. Can this somehow be considered in this code without a new loop?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is all that much better, but you could use `which()` to identify the row and column indices of the non-zero values in `m`, then use a bit of `dplyr` code to expand the list of column indices by the required length.  Then use those indices and the values to replace the appropriate cells in the matrix.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m[1, 2] <- 5
m[3, 3] <- 8
n <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=5)

w <- which(m != 0, arr.ind=TRUE)
w <- cbind(w, value=m[w])
w <- as_tibble(w) 
w <- w %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(col = list(col:(col+2))) %>%
  unnest(col)


n[cbind(w$row, w$col)] <- w$value
n
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    0    5    5    5    0
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    8    8    8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Nested loops can often be solved with `mapply()` or `outer()`.

```
#Sample Data
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
m[1, 2] <- 5
m[3, 3] <- 8
n <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=5)

#Build the function using the <<- operators, which are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned
FN <- function (i, j){
  if (m[i, j] != 0){
    n[i, j:(j+2)] <<- n[i, j:(j+2)] + rep(m[i, j], 3)
  }
}

#Outer() function to iterate, with mapply() to vectorize the if statement
outer(1:nrow(m), 1:ncol(m), FUN=function(x, y) mapply(FN, x, y))

n
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    5    5    5    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    8    8    8
```

Comment: what is `!m[i,j]==0`?? do you mean `m[i,j] != 0 `??

Comment: @onyambu lifted from OP's function, `!m==0` and `m!=0` appear to have same results, I switch to `!=` and also simplified the `vectorize()` step into an `mapply()`.